# TSLint - Preventing error: The key is not sorted alphabetically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0, lint, tslint

I'm doing a test app with Ionic2 / Cordova / Typescript / Angular.
I'm using **tslint 5.6.0**.

I'm using the following module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint

Focusing on just one file...

when linting the following file:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from "ionic-angular";
import { MyApp } from "./app.component";

import { AboutPage } from "../pages/about/about";
import { ContactPage } from "../pages/contact/contact";
import { HomePage } from "../pages/home/home";
import { TabsPage } from "../pages/tabs/tabs";

import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen";

@NgModule( {
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        TabsPage,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot( MyApp ),
    ],
    bootstrap: [ IonicApp ],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        TabsPage,
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get:

```
The key 'bootstrap' is not sorted alphabetically
RuleFailurePosition { position: 790, lineAndCharacter: { line: 25, character: 4 } }
RuleFailurePosition { position: 799, lineAndCharacter: { line: 25, character: 13 } }
```

I'm using the following options:

```
{
    "extends": "tslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "no-duplicate-variable": true,
        "max-line-length": {
            "options": [120]
        },
        "ordered-imports": false,
        "new-parens": true,
        "no-arg": true,
        "no-bitwise": true,
        "no-conditional-assignment": true,
        "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
        "no-console": {
            "options": [
                "debug",
                "info",
                "log",
                "time",
                "timeEnd",
                "trace"
            ]
        }
    },
    "jsRules": {
        "max-line-length": {
            "options": [120]
        }
    }
}
```

What option do I need to configure on TSLint to prevent showing up this error?

Comment: do you want to configure tslint not to show this error? Or how to change your code in order to adhere to the tslint rule?

Comment: I do you want to configure tslint not to show this error

Answer (score 26):

The rule failing here seems to be [object-literal-sort-keys](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/object-literal-sort-keys/).

You should be able to disable it in the **rules** section of your config file by adding:

```
"object-literal-sort-keys": false
```

You can find all the **tslint** rules [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/).

Answer (score 24):

For anyone coming here who is doing a migration to TypeScript from javascript, or who simply has a mixed codebase of javascript + typescriptm you may to define this rule inside 'jsRules' as well, i.e. to get rid of this error, when you having console statements defined inside javascript (not typescript files).

```
//tslint.json

{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],  
  "rules": {
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false //Disable for typescript
  },
  "jsRules": {
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false //Disable for javascript
  }
}
```